# Shortest ancient devout filmy literal

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, knowledge, language

Here are linked clues:

1. An ancient alphabet
2. Related to an association between measures of a circle
3. Part of a title of an English movie of an auto-biopic
4. An abbreviated form representing loyal/devout attitude, perhaps the shortest adjective

How are all of these clues linked, and what common literal do they point to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems too obvious, but maybe a partial answer:

> Pi?

1. An ancient alphabet

   > **Pi** is a letter of the Greek alphabet
2. Related to an association between measures of a circle

   > **Pi** is used to measure circumference and area of a circle
3. Part of a title of an English movie of an auto-biopic

   > @Phylyp has forced me to say "Life of **Pi**", so I'll attempt to justify it below.
   >
   > It's an American movie based on a Canadian book, so perhaps 'English' means the language as opposed to nation of origin/setting?
   > Neither the book nor the film itself is biographical, though the story itself is something of a biography being written about Pi's life (I think?  Sorry, never actually saw/read it).
   >
   > Also, the way "auto-biopic" is written makes me think we're looking for a biography about cars.
4. An abbreviated form representing loyal/devout attitude, perhaps the shortest adjective

   > **Pi**ous (but not sure about the "shortest adjective" part)

Comment: #3 - [Life of _*answer*_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi_(film))

Comment: Although with #1, I think the OP is shooting for a writing system/script, and not a specific letter in an alphabet (could be mistaken, though).

Comment: @Phylyp I considered that film, but I don't think "English" or "auto-biopic" fit.  Regarding your second comment, I agree that it's probably just part of the answer.

Comment: fair enough, it could be said the autobiography is within the fictional movie, not the movie itself.

Comment: @Phylyp Included it as well as an attempt to justify how it fits the clue.  =)

Comment: "Forced you"? LOL, darn right, no cookies for you if you don't put that in!

Comment: could also go with adding __co to your answer, a prefix for something very small/short